# How to get HTTP referer from current machine?

Tags: linux, security, hosting

I'm trying to restrict an API key for a website where my web app is hosted.
I'd like to know what the referer from my host is, so that I can define that for my API key (host offers a linux terminal).

Is there a unix command which does this?

Clarification: 
I want to to allow my web app host as the only user of the API key. Sorry if I had a wrong idea of the terminology.

Comment: I think you might be confusing some terminology here. The `Referer` header "[...] contains the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed", and is strictly a HTTP concept. Do you mean the *hostname* of your server?

Comment: @grooveplex I posted the clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the referrer is just a [Http Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). So you won't gain too much restriction if someone figures out that you are using the referrer to restrict your API key. The real restricting is done by keeping the API key secret.

As for the question the command is, literally,  hostname .

Comment: The output of the hostname command will rarely match the referer header sent by a browser visiting a website hosted on that computer.

Comment: @Quentin because it seems (to me) like the OP confusing terminology.

Comment: @Quentin I agree with  you, and wit grooveplex who said the question is unclear. The way I interpreted the question was, what would some server see as the referrer header if OP was calling a 3rd party API from some code hosted on some page on the linux box they own.

Comment: @Justyn2 The hostname is just a name. I need something more concrete for restriction settings. An IP address would be perfect.

Comment: @Saphire So if you just want to know the public IP address, you would need to have some insight into the network your host is on. Alternatively, and again only if you are talking about the public IP address of the host, you could try a service like https://ifconfig.co/ if you are able to access such a site from the host.